# Extended WPF Toolkit RichTextBox HorizontalScrollBarVisibility issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

when I am loading a text file to my window I am not getting horizontal ScrollBar at all any idea why ?

```
<UserControl x:Class="CAMXSimulator.View.LogView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended">


        <TabControl  
            AllowDrop="True"
            PreviewDragOver="DragOver"
            PreviewDrop="Drop"
            >
            <TabItem Header=" File">

            <toolkit:RichTextBox AcceptsReturn="True" 
                         AcceptsTab="True" 

                         BorderBrush="Black" 
                         BorderThickness="2" 
                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                         Name="DisplaySFMFileContents" 
                         Text="{Binding Path=VManageLogFile}"
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                         >
                <toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                    <toolkit:PlainTextFormatter />
                </toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
            </toolkit:RichTextBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header=" Headers" /> 
    </TabControl>

</UserControl>
```

It just formats the lines to be as width of the window and not how they should be .
Any idea ?

Comment: "ScrallBar" is a typo I can decipher, but what's "fgettign ile"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the WordWrap = False in order for this to work properly.  Otherwise it will wrap the text and only show the Vertical scrollbar if needed.

In looking over the code in my text project, it looks like the WordWrap keyword might not be there.  However, to enable this functionality, you can set the Document.PageWidth =  and it will prevent the text from wrapping.

Comment: Good quick answer BiggsTRC - you beat me to it :-)

Comment: @Night Walker - I see the issue.  I edited my answer to reflect a different way to do this.  I was sure WordWrap was an option.  I'll look into why we don't see it here.